# Parse.com one-to-many relationship in Android

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform, relational-database

I have problem with android implementation one-to-many relationship in [Parse.com](https://parse.com). I am trying to save relation between *Category* and *Questions* using pointers. I can get pointers (**ID**s of Question) but I don't know how to get the data they are pointing to. Is there any method to get them or do I have to call query on *Questions* class (with **ID** of *Question* I get from *Cathegory* class) ?

My code for saving relation:

```
            Question q1 = new Question("How much money cost new Skoda Fabia?", "300 " +
                    "000kc", "200 000kc", "100 000kc", "50 000kc");
            q1.saveInBackground();
            Question q2 = new Question("How much money cost new Skoda Felicia?", "300 " +
                    "000kc", "200 000kc", "100 000kc", "150 000kc");
            q2.saveInBackground();
            Question q3 = new Question("How much money cost new Skoda Octavia?", "500 " +
                    "000kc", "150 000kc", "100 000kc", "50 000kc");
            q3.saveInBackground();

            ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            questionArrayList.add(q1);
            questionArrayList.add(q2);
            questionArrayList.add(q3);

            ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("Cathegory");
            parseObject.put("Auto", questionArrayList);
            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Save was sucesfully");
                    Log.d(TAG, "error was ? : " + (e == null ? "none" : e.getMessage()));
                }
            });
```

after calling this I get this model in Parse.com :

**Category class**
[image]

**Question class**
[image]

The code for retrieving data I have written so far:

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Cathegory");
            parseQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                    List<Question> questionList = parseObject.getList("Auto");
                    //I have IDs of Question in questionList
                    for(Question q : questionList){
                        q.fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                                //Still not have all information about Question (just ID)
                                Log.d(TAG,"Data parseObject retrieved");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"Data retrieved");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by not using List but only simple pointer which is pointing from **Question** to **Category** (above is opposite)

and then I simply create Category

```
 Category sports = new Category("Sports");
 ...
 sports.save();
```

and then I use this **Category** as parameter in **Question** function

```
 setCategory(Category cat){
      put("IdCategory",cat);
 }
```

and I don't know how to use it in Android but I am using Cloud Code (JavaScript) and it looks like this :

```
 queryOnQuestion.equalTo("IdCategory", {
                                __type: "Pointer",
                                className: "Category",
                                objectId: allowedCat.get("IdCategory").id
                                });
```

And I hope that Android will be look similar. In worst case you can define cloud function with this part of code.

Hope that help somebody.